# How to configure Swagger 2 to work with Spring Web MVC (not Spring Boot)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, spring-restcontroller, springfox

I've been trying to configure Swagger 2 with Spring MVC according to [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api). It works well with Spring Boot but not with Spring MVC. I don't even get any error messages. I just get "HTTP Status 404 – Not Found".

I am working with Spring MVC 5.2.9.RELEASE and Springfox 2.9.2. This is the pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ControleGestao</groupId>
    <artifactId>ControleGestao</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <spring-mvc-version> 5.2.9.RELEASE </spring-mvc-version>
        <apache-tomcat-version>8.5.58</apache-tomcat-version>
        <servlet-version>2.0</servlet-version>
        <javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-version>1.2</javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-version>
        <org-slf4j-version>1.7.30</org-slf4j-version>
        <org-glassfish-web-version>1.2</org-glassfish-web-version>
        <!-- <jcl-over-slf4j-version>1.7.25</jcl-over-slf4j-version> -->
        <slf4j-log4j12-version>1.7.30</slf4j-log4j12-version>
        <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <hibernate-entitymanager-version>5.4.22.Final</hibernate-entitymanager-version>
        <hibernate-jpa-version>1.0.2.Final</hibernate-jpa-version>
        <spring-orm-version>5.2.9.RELEASE</spring-orm-version>
        <springfox-swagger2-version>2.9.2</springfox-swagger2-version>
        <springfox-swagger2-ui-version>2.6.1</springfox-swagger2-ui-version>
        <hibernate-validator-version>6.0.21.Final</hibernate-validator-version>
        <log4j-version>1.2.16</log4j-version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j-version>1.7.30</jcl-over-slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>${spring-mvc-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-mvc-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-mvc-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-tomcat-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${org-glassfish-web-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging Primeiro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org-slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-log4j12-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-entitymanager-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-entitymanager-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-jpa-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-orm-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2-ui-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now the dispatcher:

```java
package com.controlegestao.configs;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

    public class InicioConfigsMVC extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        
        return new Class[] {AppConfigClass.class, JPAConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
       return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

Web configuration:

```java
package com.controlegestao.configs;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.controlegestao.controllers.InicioController;
import com.controlegestao.daos.ProdutosDao;
import com.controlegestao.servicos.ProdutosServicos;

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { InicioController.class, 
                                      ProdutosDao.class, 
                                      ProdutosServicos.class
                                    })

public class AppConfigClass  {
    
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver InternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

The Swagger config as per my last attempt (since I've tried other approaches from the web):

```java
package com.controlegestao.configs;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Bean
    public Docket api()  { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
     
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I am facing the same issue.  The swagger endpoints all generate a 404, but there are no errors or warnings.